# Receive data on a udp port and forward the same on a tcp port

Tags: networking, tcp, port-forwarding, udp

I'm not sure whether this is even possible, but I want to receive some data over UDP port (say 14550) and forward it to a newly opened TCP port (say 50000). I have tried `socat` as of now but no success:

```
socat udp-recvfrom:14550,fork tcp:localhost:50000
```

What can be done?

Comment: That command should actually work. What did you test with no success? do you actually have any process accepting connections on port 50000 of your localhost?

Comment: How do you test if it's working or not? Because the command should work.